# group of buttons to change the fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I have a requirement like this

[image]

When we click on the button, different fragment should be displayed and previously selected button should be unselected.  is there any tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** there is! Simply read in to the [Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

If you are not to code a game or something else totally customizable, I dicourage you from using this design. It in no means resembles the [Android Design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed). Please check them too.

Comment: thanks for your answer. in that document they described to change the fragment. I also want to change the backrgound of currently selected button and unselect the previously selected button. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs is also useful. You can check it at [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/design/building-blocks/tabs.html).